# how to implement a thread list

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to implement a *thread_list*, like a *thread_pool*, which has interface like `add()`, `join_all()`. I just push threads into it, no need to manage the thread destroy.

I tried:

1. `thread_pool`, but it creates a group of threads at startup, for performance. But performance is not my concern, I want my *thread_list* not create any thread when it's idle, **only create thread on demand**.
2. `boost::thread_group`, but it doesn't release the threads unless itself being released, which causes more and more threads in the process.
3. `boost::asio::io_context`, I can `post` job to it, but it's single threaded, the jobs are executed in turn, I'll have to create many threads to call `io_context.run()` to make it asynchronous, in that case it's the same problem as `thread_pool`.

Here's my code:
(The first version is totally wrong, just removed)

**The Updated version**: 
(adviced by comments, use condition_variable and keep tracking all threads):

```
// thread_list.h

#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>

struct thread_list {

    thread_list();
    ~thread_list();


    typedef unsigned long long id_t;
    id_t id = 0;
    std::map<id_t, std::thread> map_thread;
    std::list<id_t> list_done;

    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;

    bool stopped = false;

    std::thread thrd_cleaner;

    void add(std::function<void()>);
};

thread_list::thread_list() 
    : thrd_cleaner([this] {
        for(;;) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

            cv.wait(lock);

            if(stopped) {
                lock.unlock();
                for(auto& pr : map_thread) {
                    pr.second.join();
                }
                return;
            }

            // get first finished thread, remove it
            if(list_done.size() > 0) {
                // remove from list_done
                auto tid = list_done.front();
                list_done.pop_front();

                // remove from map_thread
                auto iter = map_thread.find(tid);
                if(iter != map_thread.end()) {
                    iter->second.join();
                    map_thread.erase(iter);
                }
            }
        }
    })
{}

thread_list::~thread_list() {
    using namespace std;

    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lock(mtx);
        stopped = true;
    }

    cv.notify_one();
    thrd_cleaner.join();
}

void thread_list::add(function<void()> fn) {
    using namespace std;

    lock_guard<mutex> lock(mtx);
    if(stopped) return;

    auto tid = id++;
    map_thread[tid] = thread([fn, tid, this] {
        // 1. call origin function
        fn();

        // 2. mark the thread finished  
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(this->mtx);
            this->list_done.push_back(tid);
        }
        // 3. notify cleaner
        this->cv.notify_one();
    });
}
```

Test code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "./thread_list.h"

void test_normal_usage() {
    thread_list l;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) { // create 100 threads
        l.add([i]{ cout << i << endl; });
    }
}
int main() {
    test_normal_usage();
}
```

Now seems works. Need help with review, any simpler design or potential bug ?

And the `condition_variable` must be run in another thread, which causes 1 more thread at least. In production I'll create 2000+ *thread_list* for 2000+ user session, so 2000+ threads wasted. I know I can share 1 `thread_list` to all user session, but it's complicated. Maybe there's better design without increasing thread count ?

Comment: use condition variable http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/ to detect when threads are removed from `_map`

Comment: You could use a condition variable that signals when the map is empty, but it would probably be preferable to just keep your threads joinable and just join them all.

Comment: The problem here is that your list gives up thread ownership by invoking `t.detach();`. It should keep threads and then wait for them to finish by invoking `join()`. Also there is no need to create threads to make something asynchronous.

Comment: is the mutex locked by the destructor and the lambdas at the same time?

Comment: Thanks. Now it uses condition variable and keep tracking threads. I've updated the post.

Comment: boost::asio::io_context can take a concurrency_hint argument. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/io_context/overload2.html. There is also thread_pool where you're allowed to post functions to. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/thread_pool.html

Comment: @JohnKoch After googling a while, still no idea about the concurrency_hint, boost macro is too complex... And thread pool won't be my choice, I described it the post